# Jquery / Javascript — How to optimise my site load visually?

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization, positioning, loading

I'm making finishing touches on my site and am struggling to make the load of the page look less jumpy. best way to show you what i mean is to show the site:
http://marckremers.com/2011 (Still not complete, in alpha phase)

As you can see the contents sticks to the left, loads a ton of jquery and images into the page, and only then click into place (centre).

I'm wondering if there is a way i can make it click into place first and then load the elements?

I tried putting the reposition script just after , not even that works.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: @RGBK - This is unrelated to your question--but what audio player is that? I've been looking for a good non-flash audio player...

Comment: It's a highly customised Sound Cloud player. I used this: https://github.com/soundcloud/Widget-JS-API/wiki

Comment: Aside from the slow loading, your site is incredibly impressive. (:

Comment: @RGBK, I suggest that you work on your approval rate :) People will be more willing to help you.

Comment: Don't think a designer dabbling in jquery can get a very high rate :-) I ask a lot of stoopid questions. But i'm learning! S.O. is a god send.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With all of the images you have, your page is **1.5mb**, coupled with **70** http requests. No wonder your site behaves the way it does.

You should be using sprites on the smaller images to reduce http requests and as far as the large images go, you are loading all of the pictures at once. Even the ones that aren't displayed right away. The images that aren't displayed right away should be pulled in via AJAX after the page loads.

If you want to go further into optimization I would also:

- Use one external javascript file. Yes
  it increases size, but I favor that
  over http requests.
- Minify your html/javascript/css.
- Don't host jQuery on your site, use a CDN such as [Google APIS](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/).
- Check out a service similiar to Amazon S3.

I could reinvent the web site best practices wheel here, or I could send you to [Yahoo best practices for web site optimization](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html) There is a ton of very important information there, read it and reference it.

Comment: Also, you can join JS files to reduce http requests, and use jquery hosted on the CDN

Comment: This is true, I was trying to give him the basics.

Comment: Hi Nick... I'm not a pro (designer who does some jquery hacking and WP)... would love to know how to do AJAX afterloads?! Could you give me any pointers? Also with regards to having 70 http requests... what are those? How can I streamline this? Thanks man

Comment: Ok, those are great pointers. I gonna minimise the pants off this thing :-)

Comment: @RGBK, there is a lot of answers floating around on the net concerning jQuery ajax, just search. I'll edit my post to explain HTTP request.

Answer (score 1):

You loaded jQuery twice, once from your own site and another time from Google's CDN. For starters, you should probably move all the JavaScript to the bottom of your HTML. Then you need to optimize your `if ... else` that handles how many columns to display and your Google Maps iframe.

To speed the visual up, instead of using jQuery, you should probably have some vanilla DOM scripting that dynamically creates some CSS styles for the `projects` and `tb_tweets` classes, so it doesn't have to wait for all your JavaScript to load before handling resizing of your `projects` and `tb_tweets`.

Comment: Getting rid of the double load made it about twice as fast already.

Comment: Cant believe it, i just searched for "Vanilla DOM scripting" and your comment shows up first in the results... Google is... FAST! http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=vanilla+DOM+scripting

Answer (score 1):

use http://mir.aculo.us/dom-monster/ and do everything it tells you to do. If you want tools to figure out what is going on during page load, the chrome developer tools are hands down the best out there for client side optimization.

Answer (score 0):

A think you could do is put your javascript functions in the document.ready(function()), this way the functions will be loaded AFTER the page is loaded. I guess you don't need the functions for loading the site, just to interact with it?

Comment: I've done that, and all javascript is placed after the content loads. Thing is if it does it AFTER, then the composition sticks to the left margin and clicks into place after the load (which is admittedly pretty massive) just wondering if there is a way i can make it fix first, then load after?

Answer (score 0):

Generally you only want to trigger your events after the page has rendered, i.e., using

```
$(document).ready(function()) {
   //your javascript goes here
}
```

Then, in your HTML you have placeholders so the page doesn't "expand" or "jump" as you put, with some kind of indication that the element is still loading. Then, when your ajax requests complete, simply populate the placeholders with the ajax response.

Comment: Hi John, I'm not that tech, so forgive e if I'm wrong, but isnt this just jquery, not ajax? But ok, maybe I should put some inline javascript to do the layout adjustment first? I tried that by putting the repositioning script just below the body. Also, the elements are all given width and heights (most of them) even before the images load, so it should have what it needs to do the repos. Hmmm. :-/