# thumbscroller problem on Chrome and Safari - Jquery Plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, scrollbar, smooth-scrolling

Most of you probably know about thumbscroller (http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-thumbnail-scroller)

The thing is i have this problem in Google chrome and Safari that Thumbs literally 'go away' on mouse over the thumbcontainer,

if anyone feels like trying at (with crome/safari):

http://anulekha.net/production/?view=Collections&Lookbook=2011

You will quickly see what i mean, question,

any idea why is happening and how to fix t his?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I don't know about whatever version of chrome you are using, but my thumbnails aren't flaking on me.

Comment: The thumbscroll on the right on the right, neither?

Answer (score 0):

Before we dive into your jQuery thumbscroller we need to address some other issues.

With all of the images you have, your page is **2.3mb** with **83** http requests, in other words, *Houston, we have a problem.*

Developing the way you are isn't such a big deal when your creating a site that isn't composed of so many images and javascript, but with this one it is.

I suggest:

- Using sprites to combine images
- Combine all of your external JS into one and minify it, it's probably best that you minify your CSS and HTML too.
- If you can't use sprites for the thumbnails then don't load all of them on page load - Use AJAX to fetch them afterwards.
- I noticed your background image is a rather large JPEG, I bet you could reduce the file size in Photoshop without noticing a degrade in quality.

See my answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5358655/jquery-javascript-how-to-optimise-my-site-load-visually/5358813#5358813), which had similiar issues as you.

Comment: My friend, i agree with you but my customer simply will ignore my suggestions and he provided full design, layout and images. So i cant't really play much with it.. i already told them all that. Plus there are other timing/payment/soOn reasons why this is done the way it its... But, how is this related to the scroller thing? :$

Comment: @Toni, ah I know where you're coming from. I'll get back to you about the scroller in a bit.

Comment: "I'll get back to you about the scroller in a bit." :$